# Write "true" in the adjacent cell after the link is clicked

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Well, the goal of the project is to set up a VBA code that writes "true" in the adjacent cell as soon as you click on a link and false if the user has not yet clicked on the link.

I started with a small code, just to know how I was going to proceed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
        Range("B1").Value = "True"
    End If
End Sub
```

This code checks to see if the clicked hyperlink is in cell `A1`, and if it is, it writes "True" in cell `B1`.
**But the macro only works if the link is written directly in cell `A1`, and I wanted:**

1. VBA code works with a link created by the hyperlink function.
2. As long as the user has not clicked on the link, the macro must display "false" in the adjacent cell and "true" otherwise.
3. This macro must be able to be applied to all cells containing hypertext links regardless of how they were created.
4. `friendly_name` in the `hyperlink()` has to be different from the address of the link.

To fix that, I did this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim matchFound As Boolean
    
    For Each rng In Me.UsedRange
        If rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            If rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Target.Address Or rng.Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay = Target.TextToDisplay Then
                rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "True"
                matchFound = True
            Else
                If rng.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "True" Then
                    rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "False"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rng
    
    If Not matchFound Then
        MsgBox "No matching hyperlink found."
    End If
End Sub
```

**But the macro doesn't work when clicking on hyperlinks created with HYPERLINK() function, the macro should normally display "false" if the user does not click on the link but it does not work either.**

Can you help me please?

Comment: The `Hyperlink`- function doesn't trigger the FollowHyperlink-Event. But you could try using the `Worksheet_SelectionChange`-Event

Comment: As @Ike mentioned, the `Hyperlink` function doesn't trigger the `FollowHyperlink` Event. Unfortunately, `SelectionChange` Event will also not help because, this event can get triggered even with keyboard keys. And this event may not even get triggered if the hyperlink cell is already selected. Unless you move to another cell and move back. **Alternative:** Use APIs like `FindWindow` and `PeekMessage` to capture mouse clicks on a worksheet and then check if the clicked cell has a `Hyperlink` function. Not easy for a beginner but can definitely be achieved...

Comment: Oh yes I see what you mean, but I'm still a beginner and there I don't know how to go about it, can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it that doesn't rely on Worksheet events, since the `FollowHyperlink` event doesn't trigger for links created using the `HYPERLINK` function. I'm assuming that your links are to webpages, but the code could easily be modified to allow for links to other locations in the Workbook, etc.

- Create a user-defined function (UDF) that does two things: sets the value of the adjacent cell to TRUE, and opens the URL provided in the browser
- Link to the function from the `HYPERLINK` formula, providing the URL in each case.

The function looks like this:

```
Public Function GoToWebpageAndSetTrue(Webpage_Url)

    Set GoToWebpageAndSetTrue = Selection
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = True
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Webpage_Url

End Function
```

Should be pretty easy to understand. Insert this code inside a module in the Workbook to define the function.

Now, in your hyperlink cells you can type the following, for example:

```
=HYPERLINK("#GoToWebpageAndSetTrue(""https://www.google.com"")", "Link 1")
```

The double quotation marks around the URL are to escape them because they are inside another pair of quotation marks. There's not a lot of documentation online about linking to UDFs from `HYPERLINK`—I got the method from [this answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tEgi.png). Note the caveat in the answer about the importance of setting the function to `Selection` in the first line.

I created an example Worksheet that looks like this:

[image]

After clicking Link 2 (cell A2), my screen looks like this:

[image]

which is believe is what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Great it works but with my link I get an error. Here is my starting link before I use your code: `=HYPERLINK("https://wa.me/"&A2&"?text="&B2;"SEND")` it's a whatsapp link that contains a predefined message which will automatically appear in the text field of a chat. the phone number is in cell `A2` and the text is in cell `B2`. I applied your code and changed the link to `=HYPERLINK("#GoToWebpageAndSetTrue(""https://wa.me/"&A2&"?text="&B2"")"; "Link 2")` and I get the error: "Reference isn't valid" . Please how to use & while respecting double quotes to `B2` cell in that HYPERLINK FORMULA ?

Comment: Hi there. Please use: `=HYPERLINK("#GoToWebpageAndSetTrue(""https://wa.me/""&A2&""?text=""&B2)","Link2")`. I have verified that this works as intended (I am directed to the Whatsapp API page with the correct phone number and text displayed on the page). Think of it as: outer quotes around `#GoToWebpage ... &B2)` are single (`"`), inner quotes inside that are double (e.g. `""https://wa.me/""`. If my answer worked for you, please accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Your comment on double quotes helped me a lot, I tried the formula you just mentioned above but it didn't work for me (the contents of cells `A2` and `B2` were not taken into account). So here's what I tried and it works: `=HYPERLINK("#GoToWebpageAndSetTrue(""https://wa.me/"&A2&"?text="&B2&""")"; "Link 2")`. Thanks.